# Extend 2d list vertically in loop - python

Tags: python, list

I have a loop that gives me a list of lists of integers like the example bellow:

```
l1 = [[1,2],[7,8],[13,14],[19,20]]
l2 = [[3,4],[9,10],[15,16],[21,22]]
l3 = [[5,6],[11,12],[17,18],[23,24]]
```

The result I need is like a vertical extension of the lists. So the result should be:

```
l_final = [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[7,8,9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16,17,18],[19,20,21,22,23,24]]
```

Assuming that I get those lists in a loop one by one, I think I cannot use all of them at once, so a solution like some_function(l1,l2,l3) is out of the scope. Ideally, the solution would work in this structure:

```
l_final = []
for loop gives me one listOFlists:
    l1 = [[1,2],[7,8],[13,14],[19,20]]

    l_final = # solution someone? :/
```

Could somebody help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
l1 = [[1,2],[7,8],[13,14],[19,20]]
l2 = [[3,4],[9,10],[15,16],[21,22]]
l3 = [[5,6],[11,12],[17,18],[23,24]]

listOFlists = [l1, l2, l3]



l_final = []
for l in listOFlists:
    for i, sublist in enumerate(l):
        if len(l_final) >= i+1:
            l_final[i].extend(sublist)
        else:
            l_final.append(sublist.copy())

print(l_final)

#[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18], [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]]
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks, akasolace!

Answer (score 3):

Use `zip(l1, l2, l3)` to get a sequence of tuples like `([1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6])` and then use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25674169/how-does-the-list-comprehension-to-flatten-a-python-list-work) solution to flatten them:

```
[[item for sublist in x for item in sublist] for x in zip(l1, l2, l3)]
```

or more generally (thanks for the suggestion [akasolace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2629659/akasolace)), you can use `*arg` notation to unpack the `listOFlists` into arguments for the `zip` function:

```
[[item for sublist in x for item in sublist] for x in zip(*listOFlists)]
```

gives:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18], [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]]
```

Comment: this answer is really good but to make it more general (not only 3 lists) you can do following your example:
 l_final = [[item for sublist in x for item in sublist] for x in zip(*listOFlists)]

Comment: @akasolace Now done - I've credited you for suggesting it.

Comment: @akasolace I see there are now several answers including from yourself. All seem to me useful - it's nice to see the variety of methods - though I'm not completely convinced about the numpy answer because it assumes that lengths will be equal.

Comment: Good one, alaniwi! But akasolace's solution fits better in my case. I upvoted you anyway, thanks

Comment: @alaniwi, yes I am a modest contributor and I am always amazed by the general quality of answers provided. In that example, I answered but I voted for yours that I preferred to mine :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip` to group the sublists and then use `itertools.chain` to flatten it

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> lst = [l1, l2, l3]
>>> [list(it.chain(*l)) for l in zip(*lst)]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18], [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `zip` to get elements from each of the iterables and unpack the `i`, `j`, `k` inside a list using `*` operator.

```
l_final = [[*i, *j, *k] for i, j, k in zip(l1, l2, l3)]
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18], [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]]
```

Comment: this answer is really good but to make it more general (not only 3 lists) you can do following your example:
 l_final = [[item for sublist in x for item in sublist] for x in zip(*listOFlists)]

Comment: your suggestion is very good but that is already included in @alaniwi answer.

Comment: yes sorry I wanted to put that comment in his answer but picked up the wrong one (but your answer is also good :-))

Answer (score 0):

Using `numpy`:

```
li1 = np.array(l1)
li2 = np.array(l2)
li3 = np.array(l3)
c = np.concatenate((li1,li2,li3),axis=1)
```

---

**c:**

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
       [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
```